# How to swap two graphs of facet_wrap

Tags: r

I want the graphic AVANT to be in first place

```
dt = data.frame(AVG=c("POT","TPOT"),AVANT=c(5000,4400),APRES=c(5020,6500))
data = gather(dt, key="measure",value="value",c("AVANT","APRES"))
ggplot(data,aes(x=AVG, y=value,fill=AVG))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+facet_wrap(~measure)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to put measure in a factor with AVANT as the first level to put AVANT to the left of APRES:

```
data.ordered = mutate(data, measure=factor(measure, levels=c("AVANT","APRES")))
ggplot(data.ordered,aes(x=AVG, y=value,fill=AVG))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+facet_wrap(~measure)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `forcats::fct_rev` or more safely `forcats::fct_relevel` inside `fcet_wrap`, e.g.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=AVG, y=value,fill=AVG)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
facet_wrap(~fct_relevel(measure, c("APRES", "AVANT")))
#facet_wrap(~forcats::fct_rev(measure))
```

Comment: thank you very much, my problem is solved